# Aggregation query to match document on date fields in same document

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to write a query that returns all documents where the the 'ts' (timestamp) is less than a certain date (document is 3 days old) AND the 'ts' equals/matches the 'mt' (modified time) of the same document. The idea is to return all documents that have not been modified.

```js
db.posts.find(
    {   
        "ts"       : { $lt: ISODate("2015-09-19T20:44:35Z") },
        "mt"       : "ts",
        "category" : "foo"
    }
)
```

The above is obviously wrong. I am playing with the aggregation framework to try to figure this out, but open to suggestions. This needs to execute from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know PHP (to me it's an acronym for *Programmable Hyperlinked Pasta*), I am posting this as a community wiki answer so others can expand on it.

Actually, you don't need an aggregation to do this. You can simply use a [$where clause](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where) to achieve this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  ts:{ $lt: ISODate("2015-09-19T20:44:35Z") },
  $where: "this.mt == this.ts"
})
```

Others may translate this to PHP.

Comment: Thanks. That solution does work. I had read about concerns with the processing time of $where, so I'd still be interested to see how this can be achieved with aggregation.

Comment: Also, can't find an example anywhere of how to translate $where syntax into PHP.